# Java Youtube api rate comment

Tags: java, api, youtube, comments, rate

How to rate CommentEntry?
I know there is a method setTotalRating() but after calling this method, what must I do?
service.insert(sth) ?

Comment: What library are you using? What's `CommentEntry?`, you haven't told us anything to investigate on.

Comment: In Java youtube api, a comment is CommentEntry . And there is a method for commententry called setTotalRating(int x). But it doesnt actually rates the comment

Answer (score 1):

How about updating the comment?

```
YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(clientID, developer_key);
//Done with authentication...blah...blah...blah...

//Done with rating...

//Update
service.update(new URL(commentURL), commentEntry);
```

Comment: I thought it would work but I get com.google.gdata.util.InvalidEntryException: Invalid request URI

Comment: How should I get the url of a CommentEntry c? Btw thabks so much for helping me :D

Comment: I am using commentUrl = entry.getComments().getFeedLink().getHref();